# When Call Any Method - Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, exception

I have two classes:

PTS_Controller

```
using System;
using TiT.PTS;

namespace fuel_sdk_test
{
    public class PTS_Controller
    {
        private PTS pts;
        private int? pumpNumber;
        private byte? nozzleNumber;
        private int? pricePerLiter;
        private int? orderDose;
        private int[] prices;
        private int? transactionId;
        private int? atgNumber;
        private short parameterAddress;
        private byte[] parameterValue;
        private int parameterNumber;
        private bool authorizeVolume;
        private bool extendedCommands;
        private int? normalResponseTimeout = 100;
        private int? middleResponseTimeout = 200;
        private int? longResponseTimeout = 400;

        private static readonly PTS_Controller instance = new PTS_Controller();

        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static PTS_Controller()
        {
        }

        private PTS_Controller()
        {
        }

        public static PTS_Controller Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }

        public void openCom()
        {
            if (!pts.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    pts.PortName = "COM6";
                    pts.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Port opened successfully");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And My Programs.cs

```
namespace fuel_sdk_test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                PTS_Controller.Instance.openCom();
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   fuel_sdk_test.PTS_Controller.openCom() in
>   C:\Users\user\RiderProjects\fuel_sdk_test\fuel_sdk_test\PTS_Controller.cs:line
>   44    at fuel_sdk_test.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\user\RiderProjects\fuel_sdk_test\fuel_sdk_test\Program.cs:line
>   8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never initialize “pts”
Try initializing it in the constructor I think it should solve it

Comment: thank you so much this working for me

Comment: @AbdAbughazaleh How did you initialize "pts" in constructor?

Comment: @MitulPanchal just init `pts` inside of constructor